# Passing reader object from aspx.cs file to View (.aspx)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, database

**This is not a duplicate of any other question.** If there is something similar to it , so they didn't worked for me. I have searched a lot but unable to solve this issue.
Kindly guide me.

I have made a query to the database for some Records in my aspx.cs file. My records are in a reader object.
I want to access this object in the View file (.aspx file). Here is the small part of my code.

**In .Aspx.cs file**

```
String qry = "SELECT * FROM  `enduser` WHERE  `firstname` LIKE  @key LIMIT 0 , 30";
cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(qry, Connection.GetConnection().Open());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", keyword);
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

**In .Aspx file**

Can You tell me how to access it here in aspx file.

1- I have tried sessions but not worked.
2- I have tried an other way which was <% =MyVariable; %>    // Not worked

**I just want to get the reader object in the View file and then Iterate it to displat each record. Thanks**

Comment: In your code snippet above the variable `reader` is local and you haven't shown the variable `MyVariable`. Please show the real code which we should fix. Apart from that, i strongly advise against   connection-helper classes in ASP.NET like your `Connection`. All the more if it's static. Finally, in ASP.NET you don't "iterate" readers to generate HTML but you use it as DataSource for web-databound controls like `GridView`, `DataList` or `Repeater`.

Comment: The variable MyVariable is just an example its not in my code, Its the example gave by many people so i just added that as a comment, where as I also made the object reader as a public member and tried accessing it in my View file but it did not worked and gave me Null Pointer Exception. What other code you need, I will add here. I think it was sufficient.

Comment: The reason I am not using GridView or repeater is that I have did my own styling of view so I don't want a GridView. I want to display users searched on the basis of a specific keyword.
So I want to Iterate the the database result and display each row separately.

Comment: @farhangdon when using repeater for example, you define your own html, in fact it does the iteration for you. No need to do it manually, it is exactly for what you want.

Comment: You can loop through the SqlDataReader and build a table to display your rows - and style it how you like.
Or you use the SqlDataReader as the DataSource for one of the many server controls available (GridViews etc.) which will render a table which you can style how you like. Why on earth would you not use one of the existing controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use one of the controls available in ASP .NET, for example **repeater**. Then you need to bind the repeater to the datasource. The rest is done automatically.

See the example here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_data_binding.htm

Repeater example:

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp

The databinding expressions (your point 2) work in the context of databound control.

Comment: The reason I am not using GridView or repeater is that I have did my own styling of view so I don't want a GridView. I want to display users searched on the basis of a specific keyword. So I want to Iterate the the database result and and display each row seprately.

Comment: The repeater is quite flexible when it comes to styling, you define your own item template, which could be a div or anything else

Comment: Can you give me some link for custom styling a repeater ? I want to add a picture and some links in my custom repeater !!!

Comment: repeater doesn't have any styling, it uses html defined in ItemTemplate - this is rendered for each item in datasource. Columns from the datasource are those you can use in ItemTemplate, for example image url, or anything other. Example: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp